# Can only log into AWS console with IAM user if password was auto-generated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Scenario:

- I create a new IAM user and choose "AWS Management Console access" for "Access type".
- For "Console password", I choose "Custom password" and set a password.
- I attach a policy to the user allowing full access to all AWS resources.
- I log out of the console.
- Then I go to https://$MY_ACCOUNT_ID.signin.aws.amazon.com/console. I enter my Account ID, IAM user name, and password.  Every time I try logging in this way, I get a message that says "Your authentication information is incorrect. Please try again."

However, if I create another IAM user and choose "Autogenerated password" instead of "Custom password", I **can** log in with this user.

I've tried selecting different options when creating the user, but the only difference between it working and not working seems to be choosing "Autogenerated password" instead of "Custom password".

Am I doing something wrong? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50379707/2121620) is the only related info I could find.

Comment: Sorry to say this is probably user error. I can autogenerate passwords or use custom passwords with no problems. Exactly what the user error is, not sure. Copy and paste the passwords into a text editor and make sure there are no leading / trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this last week as well. I thought it was a user error so thanks for posting this question - it may actually be an AWS issue after all. I'll try once again and then open a support ticket.

In the meantime just use autogenerated password :)